# trying to read Metadata from FLAC-files with musicmetadata.js and jsmediatags.js

Tags: javascript, browser, mp3, flac

I'm a newby to web development and I'm stuck with retrieving metadata like Composer from FLAC audiofiles.

I tried to extract this information with `jsmediatags.js` and `musicmetadata.js` in Chrome with Javascript, and I could only read the title, artist, genre, picture, track and year.

My question is: am I doing something wrong, or are these libraries not supporting all the fields inside the FLAC files?

I'm happy for any help I can get.

I tried to extract all metadata from FLAC and MP3 files

Comment: Do the FLAC files contain that metadata in the first place?

Comment: Absolutely, i checked with different other software , and the tags all show up. In the mean time i tried to use a different library (FLACMetadataEditor.js) and now i can read all the Tags. Unfortunatly this library only support FLAC files and not MP* and others. Well , for the moment i'm happy with this. Thank you